# Spyder failed to launch in Anaconda after update (4.1.2)

Tags: anaconda, conda, spyder

I have just updated Spyder to 4.1.2 and when I try to launch it, it now produces an error and fails to launch.

Output from `conda list pylint`[image]
How can I solve this?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 11, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 205, in main
mainwindow.main()
File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 3734, in main
mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 3590, in run_spyder
main.setup()
File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 977, in setup
'spyder.plugins.{}'.format(plugin_name))
File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "", line 728, in exec_module
File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/plugins/pylint/__init__.py", line 14, in 
from .plugin import Pylint as PLUGIN_CLASS
File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/plugins/pylint/plugin.py", line 29, in 
from spyder.plugins.pylint.confpage import PylintConfigPage
File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/plugins/pylint/confpage.py", line 16, in 
from spyder.plugins.pylint.widgets.pylintgui import PylintWidget
File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/plugins/pylint/widgets/pylintgui.py", line 37, in 
from spyder.plugins.pylint.utils import get_pylintrc_path
File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/plugins/pylint/utils.py", line 16, in 
import pylint.config
File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pylint/config.py", line 54, in 
import toml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toml'
```

Comment: It looks like the dependencies of in the pylint package are not properly recorded. Can you give us the output of `conda list pylint`?

Comment: I have updated my question with the output. @cel

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment?

Comment: I would try `conda install "pylint<2.5"`. toml is a new dependency for pylint 2.5.0 and checking anaconda.org neither default nor conda-forge currently have a pylint 2.5 version available. I am not sure where this package comes from, but I guess it is broken.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. @cel

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an error in the pylint package provided by the default channels. The dependency `toml` is currently missing in the package definition.

A quick workaround for now is to downgrade to the previous version:

```
conda install "pylint<2.5"
```

See also [anaconda-issues/#11775](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11775).