# Spyder not launching from one of the Anaconda environments

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, opencv

I'm new to this. I have begun learning OpenCV with Python and following the course directions I've successfully created an Anaconda environment from which I can easily import CV2 and carry out my course. So far, I have experienced no problems in working with this environment.

Now, I would like to begin using Spyder which launches well from the default/base environment but does not launch from the "opencv-course" environment which I created. By contrast, Jupyter Labs and Notebooks launch well on either environment.

I've attempted to uninstall/reinstall Spyder using Administrator privileges when launching Anaconda, but to no avail.

Could anyone forward a suggestion?

Many thanks!
MD

The following error message is displayed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-course\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-course\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 205, in main
mainwindow.main()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-course\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3734, in main
mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-course\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3590, in run_spyder
main.setup()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-course\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 977, in setup
'spyder.plugins.{}'.format(plugin_name))
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-course\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked
File "", line 678, in exec_module
File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-course\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pylint\__init__.py", line 14, in 
from .plugin import Pylint as PLUGIN_CLASS
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-course\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pylint\plugin.py", line 29, in 
from spyder.plugins.pylint.confpage import PylintConfigPage
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-course\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pylint\confpage.py", line 16, in 
from spyder.plugins.pylint.widgets.pylintgui import PylintWidget
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-course\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pylint\widgets\pylintgui.py", line 37, in 
from spyder.plugins.pylint.utils import get_pylintrc_path
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-course\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pylint\utils.py", line 16, in 
import pylint.config
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-course\lib\site-packages\pylint\config.py", line 54, in 
import toml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toml'
```

Answer (score 1):

After checking out this answer here:
[Spyder failed to launch in Anaconda after update (4.1.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61529446/spyder-failed-to-launch-in-anaconda-after-update-4-1-2)

I've solved the problem by downgrading the version of Pylint from 2.5 to 2.4.4. It now works fine.

Many thanks!
MD