# spyder 4.1.0 crashing after conda update --all

Tags: anaconda, conda, spyder

I recently ran 'conda update --all' and afterwards, spyder will not start and crashes everytime I try to open it.  Error report provided.

Has anyone else has difficulties opening spyder since updating anaconda packages?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3705, in main
    mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3555, in run_spyder
    main.setup()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 973, in setup
    'spyder.plugins.{}'.format(plugin_name))

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pylint\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .plugin import Pylint as PLUGIN_CLASS

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pylint\plugin.py", line 29, in <module>
    from spyder.plugins.pylint.confpage import PylintConfigPage

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pylint\confpage.py", line 16, in <module>
    from spyder.plugins.pylint.widgets.pylintgui import PylintWidget

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pylint\widgets\pylintgui.py", line 37, in <module>
    from spyder.plugins.pylint.utils import get_pylintrc_path

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pylint\utils.py", line 16, in <module>
    import pylint.config

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylint\config.py", line 54, in <module>
    import toml

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toml'
```

Comment: I reinstalled anaconda and without running an update, spyder ran properly.  However, after updating all packages, including the new custompy package of anaconda itself, spyder returns with the same error and does not load.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61529446/spyder-failed-to-launch-in-anaconda-after-update-4-1-2#comment108865474_61529446 - see my comment there for a quick fix.

Comment: This seems to be an error in the pylint package provided by the default channels. The dependency toml is currently missing in the package definition.

A quick workaround for now is to downgrade to the previous version:

conda install "pylint<2.5"

Comment: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11775

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment?